# Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device after Google play services update

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-play-services

**Failed to start discovery.**

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zad.zad(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaE(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaD(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zar(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:24)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zai.onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zza.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzc.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:31)                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

**IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3048)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3024)                                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3007)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2949)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:9)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:14)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabt.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:7)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Note: Device had Google play service, App was working fine till yesterday, but now its giving above exception, didn't changed anything from Firebase or Google cloud platform

Test Device's Google pixel 6, OnePlus 9, Samsung j7

Any idea about how to solve this issue.

Comment: I can confirm, it is happening on all my Android devices (Samsung, Xiaomi, Huawei)